# Unable to remove website data in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, privacy, web-browsing

In `Safari --> Preferences --> Privacy --> Manage Website Data`, I'm unable to remove the data that shows up as `Databases`. I'm able to remove `Cookies` and `Cache` data but not able to remove `Databases`. Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Could you please let me know how can I remove for e.g 123greetings.com entry showing up as `Databases`?

I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: also check if there is any files in   ~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage

Comment: There are thousands of files. `ls | wc` returns `6733` files. `grep -r "123greetings" .` returns  
`Binary file ./StorageTracker.db matches`  
`Binary file ./StorageTracker.db-wal matches`. I suppose I will need to delete `StorageTracker.db` but it has tons of entries and it might also delete the ones I want to be kept. What can I try?

Answer (score 1):

go to ~Library/Safari/Databases/ and delete the database

Comment: That was pretty helpful. I deleted the `Databases.db` but it still doesn't work. I mean `123greetings.com` gets deleted only to `reappear` the next moment.